# Firebird sort table

Tags: sql, sorting, firebird

I need to sort inserted record in my table.

I try this query : `UPDATE MyTable set FieldN+1=NULL ORDER BY MyField ASC ;`, but it doesn't work.

How can I sort all inserted record in my table.

When I show all inserted record with my IDE, I need to view all record sorted.

```
1    A                          B 

     B         =>         1     A

2    C                    2     C
```

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: UPDATE has no ORDER BY. The dbms decides how to store the data. You can only specify ORDER BY when you SELECT data.

Comment: @jarlh Firebird's update supports order by, it can be used for example to update only the first n rows.

Answer (score 1):

Records in a SQL table have no internal order, and are modeled after unordered sets.  Hence, there is no notion of sorting the inserted records in your table.  If you want to impose an order, you can do that at the time you select via an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY MyField
```