# Why doesn't the last inserted row in Firebird show up at the end of table

Tags: sql, firebird

When I insert a row in a Firebird database, it doesn't show at the end of the table and it inserted before other row. Why is this?

Comment: Related: [Firebird sort table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581487/firebird-sort-table)

Comment: why even should it be shown at the end of some grid?

Answer (score 0):

Firebird doesn't use clustered tables, nor does it order data by insert. When you insert a row, Firebird adds the row to the first datapage of the table it can find that has sufficient space available. As a result, it may end up anywhere relative to other rows of the table.

If you want to enforce a specific order to the data you view, you need to add an `order by` clause to your `select` statement, specifying by which columns you want to order the data. Without an `order by`, the order of the result of a `select` is not deterministic, and may be the result of physical order in data pages, order of data in an index used to find rows, and other factors.